# App alternates light and dark mode between Cypress tests

Tags: javascript, local-storage, react-hooks, cypress

I have a React app that uses the [useDarkMode](https://github.com/donavon/use-dark-mode) hook.  It works perfectly fine in the live application, but when running my Cypress E2E tests, the app switches back and forth between light and dark mode between each test (every other `it` block is in light mode), even if I `cy.clearLocalStorage()` after each test.  My OS is set to dark mode so I would expect all tests to run in dark mode by default.

My tests are set up this way:

```js
describe('Application', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/');
  });

  it('does something', () => {
    // this will run in dark mode
  });

  it('does something else', () => {
    // this will run in light mode
  });})

  it('does another thing', () => {
    // back to dark mode
  });
});
```

I've noticed that the tests that run in light mode set the `darkMode` `localStorage` variable to `null`, while the tests that run in dark mode set it to `true`.  Could this be a bug in the way Cypress persists `localStorage`?  Or maybe a bug in the `useDarkMode` hook?

Comment: Cypress doesn't persist localStorage (by design), read the doco for an explanation

Comment: Perhaps stub localStorage? `cy.visit('/', { onBeforeLoad(win) { cy.stub(win, 'localStorage').returns(...)} })`